# Как правильно сконфигурировать pom для Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Добавил pom для проекта, изначально он был подобного вида:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ngrmr</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>OART</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <directory>out/maven_build</directory>
        <outputDirectory>myProject/out/classes</outputDirectory>
    </build>
</project>
```

Все собиралось и запускалось через консоль (`java -jar OART.jar`) корректно, но мне потребовалось добавить возможность в выходной вайл проекта добавить два файла и был добавлен плагин, после чего стало выглядеть так:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ngrmr</groupId>
    <artifactId>OART</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>OART</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <directory>out/maven_build</directory>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Плагин для maven по работе с файлами -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/out/maven_build</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>config.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/database</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>datebase.db</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <outputDirectory>out/maven_builds</outputDirectory>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

После чего возникала ошибка при запуске `no main manifest attribute`.
Вскоре был найден ответ - нужно добавить еще один плагин, добавил следующее:

```
<plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>myClasses.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Но теперь возникает следующая ошибка `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory`
Судя по всему, не может найти стороннюю библиотеку. Когда читал про maven (знания до сих пор поверхностны и я с трудом представлю как это работает), помню, что было упоминание, что нужно добавлять библиотеки так же.
Собственно вопрос - как быть? Как все-таки правильно сконфигурировать maven проект?
Конфигурация с помощью среды разработки (idea) проходит корректно без ошибок, но приходится руками копировать требуемые два файла.

**UPD** Исправлено и работает, благодарю всех советующих. Что было сделано, чтобы все заработало: у меня изначально была не стандартная (src/main/java/...) для maven структура проекта, посему пришлось добавить строку

```
<sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/</sourceDirectory>
```

в самом начале раздела `<build>` после чего возникали ошибки связанные с тем что не найдены библиотеке, которые находились локально, прописал для каждой вызывающее исключение - `<dependency>`. Финальный вариант собственно. Осталось разобраться почему собирается все в папку out/maven-build/out/maven-build.
Если кто то может посоветовать неплохой материал для изучения инструмента maven было бы здорово, к сожалению те чем я пользовался не отвечали либо я не находил ответы на поставленные вопросы

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>OART</groupId>
    <artifactId>jar-build-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- настройки проекта -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>

        <!-- каталог сборки конечного дистрибутива -->
        <distrib.directory>${project.basedir}/out/maven-build</distrib.directory>

        <!-- версии используемых библиотек -->
        <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>

        <!-- версии используемых плагинов -->
        <plugin.jar.version>2.6</plugin.jar.version>
        <plugin.dependency.version>2.10</plugin.dependency.version>
        <plugin.resources.version>2.7</plugin.resources.version>
        <plugin.compiler.version>3.1</plugin.compiler.version>
        <plugin.exec.version>1.4.0</plugin.exec.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Здесь добавляете ваши зависимости, например -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev15-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-data-spreadsheet-v3</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <!--
                Compiler plugin
                Указывает используемую версию JDK
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                Resources plugin
                Копирует файлы ресурсов в каталог сборки проекта
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- копируем файлы ресурсов в ${distrib.directory} -->
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/out/maven-build</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>config.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/database</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>datebase.db</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                Dependency plugin
                Копирует зависимости в каталог сборки проекта
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.dependency.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- копируем библиотеки в ${distrib.directory}/lib -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/out/maven-build/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                JAR plugin
                Собирает исполняемый JAR файл
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.jar.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/out/maven-build</outputDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>myClasses.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                Exec plugin
                Для запуска проекта из IDE или командной строки
            -->
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы немного путаетесь, поэтому предлагаю простой пример проекта, который:

- использует одну зависимость / библиотеку
- выполняет сборку дистрибутива во внешний каталог (копирует в него используемые ресурсы и библиотеки)
- может запускаться из командной строки или IDE

**Структура каталогов:**

```
> tree jar-build-project /F
│   config.properties
│   pom.xml
├───data
│       database.db
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   └───java
│   │       └───org
│   │           └───example
│   │                   Main.java
```

**Main.class**

```
package org.example;

// используем стороннюю библиотеку для примера
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(StringUtils.join("Hello", " ", "world!"));
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jar-build-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- настройки проекта -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>

        <!-- каталог сборки конечного дистрибутива -->
        <distrib.directory>${project.basedir}/distrib</distrib.directory>

        <!-- версии используемых библиотек -->
        <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>

        <!-- версии используемых плагинов -->
        <plugin.jar.version>2.6</plugin.jar.version>
        <plugin.dependency.version>2.10</plugin.dependency.version>
        <plugin.resources.version>2.7</plugin.resources.version>
        <plugin.compiler.version>3.1</plugin.compiler.version>
        <plugin.exec.version>1.4.0</plugin.exec.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Здесь добавляете ваши зависимости, например -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--
                Compiler plugin
                Указывает используемую версию JDK
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                Resources plugin
                Копирует файлы ресурсов в каталог сборки проекта
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- копируем файлы ресурсов в ${distrib.directory} -->
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>config.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/data</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>database.db</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                Dependency plugin
                Копирует зависимости в каталог сборки проекта
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.dependency.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- копируем библиотеки в ${distrib.directory}/lib -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                JAR plugin
                Собирает исполняемый JAR файл
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.jar.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                Exec plugin
                Для запуска проекта из IDE или командной строки
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.exec.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Пробуем запустить. Я делаю из командной строки - все тоже самое выполняется при настройке конфигурации запуска в вашей IDE.

```
D:\Eclipse\jar-build-project>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jar-build-project 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Eclipse\jar-build-project\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (copy-resources) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Eclipse\jar-build-project\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Eclipse\jar-build-project\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Eclipse\jar-build-project\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] commons-lang3-3.4.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Eclipse\jar-build-project\distrib\jar-build-project-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ jar-build-project ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Eclipse\jar-build-project\distrib\jar-build-project-1.0.jar to C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\example\jar-build-project\1.0\jar-build-project-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing D:\Eclipse\jar-build-project\pom.xml to C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\example\jar-build-project\1.0\jar-build-project-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Из вывода команды пошагово видно какие плагины и как отработали. Смотрим содержимое каталога `/distrib`:

```
>tree /F
│   config.properties
│   database.db
│   jar-build-project-1.0.jar
└───lib
        commons-lang3-3.4.jar
```

Пробуем запустить:

```
>java -jar jar-build-project-1.0.jar
Hello world!
```

---

В ходе разработки вы можете запускать проект через `maven-exec-plugin`. Для этого нужно в корне проекта выполнить команду:

`mvn exec:java`.

Или создать конфигурацию запуска с такой командой в IDE.

Comment: В том то и дело - собирал с помощью IDE и работал через консоль проблем не имел, но тут возникало желание попробовать jenkins и тут начались проблемы с maven'om. Благодарю за развернутый ответ, как переконфигурирую pom обязательно отпишусь! Еще раз благодарю.

Comment: А не могли бы пояснить момент связанный с <dependencies>
        <!-- Здесь добавляете ваши зависимости, например -->
        <dependency> - в вашем случае вы объявляете зависимость в которой присутсвует сторонняя apach библиотке, коих в моем проекте нет. Я правильно понимаю что это те зависимости, которые позволяют пользоваться той или иной библотекой удаленно без ее локального присутствия? Если в моем проекте таковых нет, то этот пункт соотвественно не нужен?

Comment: Если в вашем проекте вы вообще не используете сторонние библиотеки, то объявлять их в `<dependencies>`, конечно, не нужно - просто удалите всю секцию. Когда вы объявляете зависимость, Maven скачивает соответсвующую библиотеку из [центрального репозитория](http://search.maven.org/) и помещает ее в локальный репозиторий на вашем ПК, который находится в каталоге `%USER_HOME%/.m2`. Т.е. библиотеки всегла хранятся локально, но в случае Maven организованы в виде репозитория, а не раскиданы по каталогам проектов.

Comment: Я использую несколько библиотек, но автоматически подтянулось только log4j, на остальные среда разработки помечает как неверные для использование, такие как google-java-api-client, sqlite-jdbc и другие. Еще вопрос - на данный момент возникает ошибка во время сборки проекта JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion! что ведет за собой то что при запуске jar у меня не определяется класс main. Возможно ли как нибудь изменить стандартный (src/main/java) путь до класса c main методом?

Comment: В предыдущем комментарии я вам оставил ссылку на Maven Central, ищите все библиотеки там. Вот [Google API Client](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.api-client|google-api-client|1.21.0|jar), например. Просто скопируйте содержимое **Dependency Information**. Поменять можно, за это отвечает свойство `sourceDirectory`, но непонятно зачем.

Comment: Благодарю. Когда я начинал данный проект не рассчитывал на работу с maven и не знал корректных (по крайней мере для maven) путей по умолчанию для класса Main